Topological interpretation of the existence part of the valuative criterion for properness
Let $X$ be a complex analytic space. I am trying to understand if there is a topological counterpart to the existence part of the valuative criterion for properness. The latter reads: every (ADDED: rational) map  $\mathbb{D}^* \to X$ out of the punctured disk, admits a (not necessarily unique) extension out of the whole disk $\mathbb{D} \to X$.
This looks similar to me to "local sequential compactness", i.e. for every $p \in X$, there exist an open set $p \in U$ and a sequentially compact set $K$ containing $U$.
Any thoughts/counterexamples? Perhaps I should add some extra hypotheses on $X$?

Does the valuative criterion work as stated for complex spaces? I’m afraid that essential singularities will ruin the analogy with algebraic geometry. For example, consider the map $\mathbb{D}^*\to \mathbf{P}^1$ given by $(e^{1/z}:1)$. It doesn’t extend across the puncture since the function is not meromorphic at zero.

You are correct, my bad. Perhaps this can be fixed by requiring the map out of $\mathbb{D}^*$ to be a rational map in the first place?

Let $X$ be a compact complex-analytic space (not necessarily Hausdorff). Let $U\subset X$ be an open. Let's say that a map $D*\to U$ has no essential singularities if it extends to a morphism $D\to X$. Then the following are equivalent I believe: 1) U is compact and 2) Every morphism $D*\to U$ without essential singularities extends to a morphism $D*\to U$.

@AriyanJavanpeykar I agree this should be true if $U$ is a Zariski open. Does it hold for all opens? Take $U$ to be the open unit disc inside $X=\mathbf{P}^1$. Then every map $f:D \to X$ sending $D^*$ into $U$ sends the origin into $U$ (since the image of $D\to X$ is open (if $f$ is not constant) and contained in $U\cup {f(0)}$). But $U$ is not compact.

@PiotrAchinger First, apologies for the many typos. The first two $D*$ are supposed to be $D^$ and the final $D$ was supposed to be just $D$. TBC

@PiotrAchinger The implication 1) implies 2) always holds. Take a sequence $z_n$ convering to $0$ in $D^\ast$. Then $f(z_n)$  is a sequence in $U$ which converges to $f(0)$  (in $X$) which by compactness of $U$ then lies in $U$.

@PiotrAchinger But your comment shows that 2) implies 1) does not always hold for Euclidean opens. My guess is as yours: it probably holds for all Zariski-opens of $X$.

This is very helpful, thank you! My question is related but slightly tangential to this. I am thinking at the case where the valuative criterion of univ closed does not imply universal closedness, because $X$ fails to be of finite type. For example, $X=\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology.
